# Video, and image files merge using FFMPEG in android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I want to merge video and images in single video file like following with dynamic.

For example:
Video-1 + Image-1 (3 sec should be display) + Video-2 + Image-2 (3 sec should be display) ...

So, video and image will be dynamic and different resolution.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why do you emphasize the fact that this will happen on Android? The ffmpeg command is the same command.

Comment: @AlexCohn Is there any possibility to do using other solution?

Comment: Well, there is no law that requires video editing to be done with ffmpeg, but it's the most common solution. Why do you need something else?